# Replicate curl command to access Smartsheet in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smartsheet-api

I am trying to access Smartsheet through API 2.0 in a Ruby-on-Rails app.  I can get he following curl command to work

```
curl --request GET https://api.smartsheet.om/2.0/sheets -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

All attempts to replicate in Ruby code have failed.  Can anyone help convert to Ruby?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a handful of options to accomplish that. If you want to keep close to curl as you have proposed, you could capture the response of the curl command wraping it with backticks

```
response = `curl --request GET https://api.smartsheet.om/2.0/sheets -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`
```

I'd recommend, however, use something like [CURB](https://github.com/taf2/curb), which provides Ruby binding for libcurl. It would add some syntax sugar, so your request would look like

```
response = Curl.get("https://api.smartsheet.om/2.0/sheets") do |http|
  http.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
end
```

Yet another option would be ditching curl altogether and use a gem like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). It makes use of Ruby's `net/http` to make requests.

That would be something along these lines:

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://api.smartsheet.om/2.0/sheets",
           headers: 'Authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

Comment: Thanks!  #2 worked great.  Couldn't get #3 to work but still working on it.  I have a solution!